# Minimal frequency of unspecified drum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, dispersion, normal-modes

I was given the following wave function, related to an unspecified drum:

$$\frac{\partial ^2Ψ}{\partial t^2}=c^2 \left ( \frac{\partial ^2Ψ}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial ^2Ψ}{\partial y^2} \right )-\gammaΨ.$$

I was asked to find an expression for the frequency, which led me to:
$$ω=\sqrt{c^2(k_x^2+k_y^2)-γ}$$

I was then asked for the minimal frequency of the drum.

Now here is my question: had there been any information as to the shape of the drum (we have studied rectangular, round and square drums), I would know how to proceed. But this information is purposefully left out, and I have no idea how to approach the question without it. How can one come up with the minimum frequency without the basic geometric data + boundary conditions leading to the normal modes, substituting for $k_x$ and $k_y$ accordingly?

Any insights are very much appreciated!

Comment: Hint: the general solution must include all harmonics indicated with $\omega_n$ and the question is asking about $\omega_1$.

Comment: Hi John! Sure, but I don't see how I can avoid having to define $k_x$ or $ky$ via boundary conditions, which purposefully aren't given. I mean, otherwise how do you get to $ω1$?

Comment: Oh yeah, $k_{ii}$ need to be quantized to the BC as only integer multiples fit on the drum.

Comment: so how do you even begin to analyse that if the shape of the drum isn't given?

Comment: IDK. There is a minimum tension that keeps the square root real though.